# vbox - Ubuntu 20.04 Unity desktop gives a black screen on booting

Tags: boot, 20.04, unity, virtualbox

to get a taste of Ubuntu..
I installed Ubuntu 20.04 in a vbox via this [site](https://codepre.com/how-to-use-mini-iso-to-perform-a-clean-ubuntu-20-04-or-18-04-installation-via-unity.html?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=pmd_d3bd84c85db5d3247581fcb0a1ef2f20577b1d37-1629016128-0-gqNtZGzNAjijcnBszQbO)

After installing everything..
I ran the vm..

It started.. but one problem..
The whole screen is black..
I waited for 5 minutes thinking it to be a "first boot thing"...
But i was wrong..

Still the black screen!

VM info:

```
settings:
  + type: Ubuntu x64
system:
  + base memory: 1404 MB
  + 2 CPUs given
display:
  + video memory: 128mb
  + monitors: 1
  + enable 3d accleration: Unchecked
```

VBox Version: v5.2.44 (because i have a x86 laptop)

HOST info:

```
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Architecture: x86
```

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 is 64-bit only. 1400 MB does not meet the minimum requirements for 20.04 Desktop. Some 20.04 applications and libraries are 32-bit, but the entire 20.04 desktop stack is not, so building from a Netboot (minimal) .iso is not a workaround. Try Ubuntu 18.04, which has a real 32-bit version. Alternately, Debian builds 32-bit desktops also.

Comment: @user535733 thanks for the suggestion.. I will try again with Ubuntu 18.04 (32-bit) and tell the result with that..

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements  (your available video RAM is half the minimum required (256MB min, you have 128MB); Unity was *slightly* less than GNOME is, but even if you go back to the LAST Unity release (17.04) the 256 MB minimum for graphics was present - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements?action=recall&rev=116   You'll be able to run *flavors* of Ubuntu with more luck (I've hardware that I stopped using Unity 7 on at 16.04 as it was no longer *fun*, but *flavors* or the lighter desktops were fine)